Clarifying the Well-Definedness of Symplectic Reduction in the Kempf-Ness Theorem
The Kempf-Ness theorem states that if we are in the following situation 
Where $K < G$ is a compact real subgroup whose complexification is $G$, $X$ a projective variety. Then the GIT quotient $X//G$ and the symplectic reduction $X//K$ are
equal (as sets).
My question is how can we perform the symplectic reduction in this case since $X$ is not necessary a symplectic manifold ?
Many references invoke the Marsden-Weinstein-Meyer theorem to provide a well-defined quotient under symplectic reduction, but this requires
$X$ to be a symplectic manifold. So, how is the quotient $X//K$ defined in this context? Is it still a manifold, and how does the symplectic structure come into play?

The $X$ in question is smooth and projective. Therefore, you can embed into projective space smoothly. It then inherits a symplectic form, via pullback.

@QuaereVerum So $\mathbb{P}^n$ with the Fubini-Study is symplectic ?

Yes. This knowledge is a prerequisite for understanding the Kempf-Ness theorem.

@QuaereVerum I know, I just needed someone to confirm this since it's not mentioned in any of the references.
